# Send Message from Server to Multiple Devices Through GCM in Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

> Send Message from Server to Multiple Devices Through GCM in Android

I Want to Make 2 apps :

1. Server app (For Sending Messages)
2. Client App (For Receiving Messages, Client Devices are multiple)

When Server sends the message, multiple devices should receive that message.

Also the messages should be saved.

Can Anyone help me, I tried everything but i all i get is bugs.

Comment: Please post the error you get..

Comment: Post what you have tried and the error logs.

Comment: i tried this tutorial : http://www.androidhive.info/2016/02/android-push-notifications-using-gcm-php-mysql-realtime-chat-app-part-1/

Comment: Please post your error logs. Try to read the Official Google Documentation for GCM https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client and https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/

Comment: Have a look at this sample to get started https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm